# Is there something like terraform's .tfstate file in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, terraform

I'm a newbie to boto3. I want to build the aws infrastructure using boto3. But in case if i want to destroy that infra and build a new one, is there any file like terraform's .tfstate in boto3 which i can use it to destroy the infrastructure using it?

If not present then how can the terraform destroy can be achieved using boto3?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

Comment: That's not really what boto is for.  Why not just use Terraform?

Comment: For creating multiple subnets, I cant use something like for loops as in terraform. And also using terraform, i cant make my code completely scalable, that's the main reason to move to boto.

Comment: I think you're maybe asking the wrong question here and instead should be asking about how you make your Terraform code "more scalable" (with an example and a tighter scope than that) because there's some very large users of Terraform that have managed to achieve this.

Comment: @VinayWadagavi terraform supports looping through subnets using its interpolation syntax: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html

Answer (score -1):

So if you use boto3 within a programming language, you will have to save state identifiers as tags, and handle that logic within the code. Thats the case with imperative languages, its built on logic, so you decide what you need.

Terraform, is specialised declarative state language, engineered to built infra as code, and offers tfstate as a feature.

With ansible, you tag your resources, so although it does not save the state, it performs lookup on tags to check if a resource already exists.

Hope this helps.